# Jasper title block divide into three parts

Tags: jasper-reports

How i can divide jasper title into 3 parts so that left part contain center image and right part contain center image and middle part contains multiple line text. **each text size, color be different**.

example:

```
----------------------------------
|          |  text 1  |          |
|          |  text 2  |          |
|   center |  text 3  |  center  |
|   image  |  text 4  |  image   |
|          |  text 5  |          |
----------------------------------
```

How i can achieve this. how `column divide` works here or i need to use something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by manually set height, width and position of each element.

Lets title height = 100, width = 555.

> For first block: `x = 0`, `y = 100`, `width = 100`
>
> For second block: for each text: `x = 0`, `y = 20`, `width = 355`
>
> For third block: `x = 455`, `y = 100`, `width = 100`

Hope this will help to solve the problem.